# Running a script via cron at a random time, but a certain number of times per day

Tags: ubuntu, cron, scheduling

I want to be able to run my script, say, 2 or 3 times per day -- 24 hours -- but at a different time each time.

What would you recommend **a simple and reliable** solution?

Comment: Does the script run for more than one minute? In other words, if the "randomly" suggested times were 12:01am and 12:02am, would that be OK?

Comment: Should your script run two or three times per day? Or is this part of the randomness? Do the times need to be "approximately" equidistant or could they be three consecutive minutes? If the script is supposed to run "two or three times", would it be acceptable if occasionally the script ran only once in a 24 hour period?

Comment: I would take the one you found before the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run the script 2 times per day:

```
0 0,12 * * * sleep $(( $$ \% 21600 )); /path/to/script.sh
```

This will start the job at noon and midnight, then sleep for up to 6 hours (half of the 12-hour interval) before starting the script.

To run the script 3 times per day:

```
0 0,8,16 * * * sleep $(( $$ \% 14400 )); /path/to/script.sh
```

This will start the job at midnight, 8am, and 4pm, then sleep for up to 4 hours (half of the 8-hour interval) before starting the script.

Since you tagged this with Ubuntu, you likely have bash as the default /bin/sh, which seems to interpret $RANDOM (despite RANDOM not being POSIX-specified), so for extra unpredictability, adjust Zwans' answer to:

2 runs per day:

```
0 0,12 * * * sleep $(( RANDOM \% 21600 )); /path/to/script.sh
```

3 runs per day:

```
0 0,8,16 * * * sleep $(( RANDOM \% 14400 )); /path/to/script.sh
```

I changed the `&&` to `;`, which changes the meaning from "wait until the sleep command exits successfully" to "sleep for some amount of time, then regardless of whether sleep completed or was killed". Also note that the [`%` needs to be escaped](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) when it is part of a cron command, otherwise it is interpreted as a newline.

Comment: so what are the procs and cons of RANDOM vs $$ ?

Comment: If you have to deal with a basic /bin/sh, it may not provide $RANDOM, but POSIX mandates that it provide $$, which was the closest to a "random" number I could get.

Comment: I don't understand, what should I use?

Comment: If you use the lines with `RANDOM` which is a variable specific to `bash`, you must add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to your crontab.

Comment: Why restrict the "sleep window" to half of the interval? Does this not unnecessarily reduce the randomness and always runs the script during the first half of each interval?

Comment: @pastic I did that so that the runs would be more-evenly spaced out. We didn't hear back on my earlier question of "is 12:01am and 12:02am OK?" so my interpretation of a "simple, reliable" solution was to separate the runs with a half-interval random delay.

Answer (score -1):

`0 */12 * * * sleep $((RANDOM%x)) && /bin/sh -c /path/to/script.sh`

Your delay will be between 0 and `x`, so set this value yourself. This should run every 12 hours, with a random delay.

Make sure this is run using `bash`.

Comment: Cron uses `/bin/sh` on most systems, but you could also just move the `sleep` into the script itself. Just set up cron entries for the number of times you'd like to launch the script, and have the scrip `sleep` a random amount of time (between 0 and the number of seconds until the next cron job kicks off).

Comment: also beware that `%` is cron-speak for a newline, so you'd need to escape it.